# Deserialize XML to exact Class only

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

is there a way to force the XML Deserialize to convert only to an exact matching class object and throw an exception (or error) if it does not match exactly?

The following code will successfully import all 3 xml files:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlDeserialize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {           

            Person data;

            XmlSerializer xs = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] { typeof(Person) })[0];

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\exact.xml"))
            {
                data = (Person)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\reduced.xml"))
            {
                data = (Person)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\extended.xml"))
            {
                data = (Person)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }


    public class Person
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;            
    }
}
```

exact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>MyName</Name>
    <Age>9999</Age>
</Person>
```

The exact.xml fits exactly and therefore it should be possible to deserialized it without any problem

reduced.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>MyName</Name>
</Person>
```

To be honest, I expected that I will receive an error by using reduced.xml, but it will be deserialized without a problem. I thought that if "Age" is not nullable (int?) I will receive an error and not the default value of an int. Spezially when keeping in mind that the following code will lead to a compiler error.

```
int x;
MessageBox.Show("x: " + x); //Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'x'
```

Therefore the successful deserialization is strange for me but somehow explainable....

But what I completely cannot understand is that fact that I do not receive an error when using the following xml file:

extended.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>MyName</Name>
    <Age>9999</Age>
    <Address>MyAddress</Address>
</Person>
```

The deserialization completely ignores that he is not able to assign "Address" to any class property....

Is it possible to force an exact parsing?
Best for me would be to receive an error by using reduced.xml and extended.xml but at least when using extended.xml I should receive an error....

BR,
MUT

Comment: You can use a schema and make a property required.  If the property doesn't have a value the schema check will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to schemas! Test application shows that it could fulfill the described use case. sadly it is only possible to autogenerate schemas, when all properties are part of a single dll.

Comment: A schema has a INCLUDE statement where you can add a 2nd child schema to a main schema.  So each dll can have its own schema and then combine the schemas using an Include in one of the schemas.

Comment: Thanks for the additional hint. so it should be easily possible to create a over all schema from bottom to top DLLs - Thanks!!

Comment: A schema defines types and the properties of each type which is equivalent to classes and their properties.  So the schema is just a xml description of your classes.  The schema should be organized to match your application structure.